# MapCache not storing files

Tags: mapserver, mapcache

I'm using MapCache with MapServer.
When I use the link to MapCache the map is served but I look in the `/tmp/mapcache` directory and no files are list.  I've made the `/tmp/mapcache` directory world writable and still no luck.

Here is my `mapcache.xml`

```
<mapcache mode="combined_mirror">
   <cache name="disk" type="disk">
           <base>/tmp/mapcache</base>
      <symlink_blank/>
   </cache>

   <source name="vmap0" type="wms">
      <getmap>
         <params>
            <FORMAT>image/jpeg</FORMAT>
            <LAYERS>default</LAYERS>
         </params>
      </getmap>

      <http>
         <url>http://192.168.112.225/cgi-bin/mapserv?transparent=true&map=/usr/lib/cgi-bin/osm-bw.map</url>
      </http>
   </source>

   <tileset name="mirror">
      <source>vmap0</source>
      <cache>disk</cache>
      <grid>WGS84</grid>
      <grid>g</grid>
      <format>png</format>
      <metatile>5 5</metatile>
      <metabuffer>10</metabuffer>
              <!--<expires>3600</expires>-->
   </tileset>


   <default_format>png</default_format>

   <service type="wms" enabled="true">
      <full_wms>assemble</full_wms>
      <resample_mode>bilinear</resample_mode>
      <format>png</format>
      <maxsize>4096</maxsize>
      <forwarding_rule name="catch all">
            <http>
              <url>http://192.168.112.225/cgi-bin/mapserv?transparent=true&map=/usr/lib/cgi-bin/osm-bw.map</url>
            </http>
      </forwarding_rule>
   </service>
   <service type="wmts" enabled="true"/>
   <service type="tms" enabled="true"/>
   <service type="kml" enabled="true"/>
   <service type="gmaps" enabled="true"/>
   <service type="ve" enabled="true"/>
   <service type="demo" enabled="true"/>

   <errors>report</errors>
   <lock_dir>/tmp</lock_dir>
   <log_level>debug</log_level>

</mapcache>
```

The Apache `mapcache.conf`

```
<IfModule mapcache_module>
   Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
   <Directory /mapcache>
      Order Allow,Deny
      Allow from all
   </Directory>
   MapCacheAlias /mapcache "/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mapcache.xml"
</IfModule>
```

If I run `mapcache_seed` with this xml file it seems to generate the cache files properly

Comment: Did you `chown ww-data:www-data /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mapcache.xml`?

Comment: No I did not but I did just now.  It didnt make a difference.  However the file is world readable and mapcache is returning an image.  Its just not writing the image to disk.